# How to avoid null reference exceptions when iterating through IEnumerable datarow?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a translation map that looks like this:

[image]

I have a query that goes and grabs the translations from each one of the rows above:

```
var fieldType="Gender";
var translateFrom = "F";

IEnumerable<DataRow> row = from dataRow in translations.AsEnumerable()
                           where dataRow.Field<string>("TranslateFrom").ToLower().Trim() == translateFrom
                                 && dataRow.Field<string>("FieldType").ToLower().Trim() == fieldType
                           select dataRow;

var translateTo = (string)row.FirstOrDefault()?["TranslateTo"];
```

However for some reason I am getting exceptional behavior when it iterates through this data row:

[image]

If for example I set the `translateFrom` to empty string:

```
var translateFrom="";
```

Then I get a null reference exception on this line:

```
var translateTo = (string)row.FirstOrDefault()?["TranslateTo"];
```

The goal is to have `string.Empty` be translated to `U` as seen above in the translation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the `TranslateFrom` value null (i.e. `DBNull.Value`)?  If so, I'd expect a null reference exception at `dataRow.Field<string>("TranslateFrom").ToLower()`.  What about trying `dataRow["TranslateFrom"].ToString().ToLower()` instead? I'd expect this to work as DBNull.Value.ToString() is an empty string.

Comment: `row` should be named `rows` since it represents a collection.

Comment: @joe thats an awesome idea, but what happens is the collection `IEnumerable<DataRow> row ` is empty

Comment: @AlexGordon - Take FirstOrDefault and check for null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a little extension method like this:

```
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static string NullSafe(this string s){
        if(s == null){
            return "";
        }
        return s;
    }   
}
```

And then use it like this to convert null data to empty string:

```
dataRow.Field<string>("TranslateFrom").NullSafe().ToLower().Trim()
```

Comment: you are a genius! thank you my friend